# Is there a way to measure or change how fast a Windows Server 2012 rehydrates data that it previously deduplicated?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, backupexec, deduplication

Since the deduplication option was enabled on the Windows Server (currently at about 40 percent deduplication rate overall), the speed of the Backup Exec 16 job became much slower - less than 30 percent of the speed observed previously. Apparently, Backup Exec can back up only non-optimized, i.e. non-deduplicated data. Accordingly, it seems that the Windows Server needs to rehydrate the data before it can be written to tape. Still, I wonder if there isn’t a way to optimize the whole process so that backups are completed faster. Any thoughts?

Comment: This would be better directed to vendor support.

Comment: Sounds like you get to make a tradeoff between backup speed and disk usage.